# Drawing a k-ary tree using TikZ without overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to draw a k-ary tree using tikz.

[image: Nice K² Tree]

Unfortunately I couldn't manage to avoid the nodes from overlapping. I also tried setting `level/.style={sibling distance=30mm/#1}, growth parent anchor=south` and experimenting with the settings, but so far to no avail. It would be nice if there would be no space at the top node position (like the original tree).

[image: Overlapping Tree]

This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node{}
  child {node {1}
    child {node {1}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
      } 
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {1}}
      }
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {1}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
      }
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {1}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
      }
    }
  }
  child {node {0}}
  child {node {1}
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}}
  }
  child {node {1}
    child {node {1}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}} 
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If there's a pattern, you can draw it programmatically, if you wish. Is there?

Comment: There is:
If a parent node has value 1, it has k children, otherwise it has 0.

Comment: @janB That's not sufficient a pattern to determine the values of the *k* children though.

Comment: You're right I thought about writing some code, in order to just supply a bitvector level-wise e.g.
l1=1011
l2=110101001000
that would be useful in this case, but I don't think the time used for developing this will be spent wisely. I might write a small script though, which generates the code below, if I need it often.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `forest`. It automatically spaces nodes to make as compact a tree as possible, and has a much easier syntax.  Depending on your needs, you could also generate the tree programmatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
  [1
    [1
      [1
        [0]
        [1]
        [0]
        [0]
      ] 
      [1
        [0]
        [0]
        [1]
        [1]
      ]
      [0]
      [0]
    ]
    [1
      [1
        [0]
        [0]
        [1]
        [0]
      ]
      [0]
      [0]
      [0]
    ]
    [0]
    [1
      [0]
      [0]
      [0]
      [1
        [0]
        [0]
        [1]
        [0]
      ]
    ]
  [0]
  [1
    [0]
    [1
        [0]
        [1
          [1]
          [0]
          [1]
          [0]
        ]
        [0]
        [1
          [1]
          [0]
          [0]
          [0]
        ]
    ]
    [0]
    [0]
  ]
  [1
    [1
        [1
          [0]
          [1]
          [1]
          [0]
        ]
        [1
          [0]
          [1]
          [0]
          [0]
        ]
        [1
          [0]
          [1]
          [0]
          [0]
        ]
        [0]
    ]
    [0]
    [0]
    [0]
 ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that `forest` is really the right tool for the job. Appearently, to do this as you wanty with TikZ you need to use the algorithms of `graphdrawing` library, which require LuaLaTeX (See section 26 for the GraphDrawing engine and 21 for the customizable tree keys of the [TikZ Manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout, level 4/.style={sibling distance=0.01em}]
\node{}
  child {node {1}
    child {node {1}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
      } 
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {1}}
      }
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {1}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
      }
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {1}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {0}}
      child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}}
        child {node {0}}
      }
    }
  }
  child {node {0}}
  child {node {1}
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {1}
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {0}}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}}
  }
  child {node {1}
    child {node {1}
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {1}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {1}}
          child {node {0}}
          child {node {0}}
        }
        child {node {0}}
    }
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}}
    child {node {0}} 
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the second number of the second level (the 0), it's not where it's supposed to be, I don't know why and tried a lot of keys to position it better but all unsuccessfully, since I don't know what happens behind the scenes...